# How to check that perf events are enabled in Linux kernel, and how to install perf userland as non-root?

Tags: linux, kernel, gentoo, software-installation, perf-event

From what I have checked it looks like kernel side of 'perf' subsystem is enabled on computer I work on.

Checking kernel configuration shows the following

```
$ zgrep "_PERF[_= ]" /proc/config.gz 
CONFIG_HAVE_PERF_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_PERF_COUNTERS is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_PERF_EVENTS_NMI=y
```

I also did the check described in [perf_events FAQ](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~vweaver1/projects/perf-events/faq.html):

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
1
```

But the **`perf` tool** is not installed:

```
$ perf
-bash: perf: command not found
$ /sbin/perf
-bash: /sbin/perf: No such file or directory
$ /usr/sbin/perf
-bash: /usr/sbin/perf: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to install perf userland as an ordinary user, to one's own home directory (for '2.6.36-gentoo-r4' kernel)?

Or do I need to ask administrator of machine in question to install it?  More unfortunately `dev-util/perf` package on Gentoo is masked (blocked) on amd64:

```
$ emerge --search perf
[...]
*  dev-util/perf [ Masked ]
      Latest version available: 2.6.35_rc4
      Latest version installed: [ Not Installed ]
      Size of files: 73,503 kB
      Homepage:      http://perf.wiki.kernel.org/
      Description:   Userland tools for Linux Performance Counters
      License:       GPL-2
```

Comment: This question should IMHO use `perf_events` tag... but it does not exists yet, and I don't have enough reputation to add it.

Comment: Did you try looking for `perf` instead of `prof`?

Comment: @cjm: Thanks, rechecked just in case, and fixed.  (Its 'perf' not 'prof', but it is 'gprof' not 'gperf'...).

Comment: +1 for `zgrep "_PERF[_= ]" /proc/config.gz`

Answer (score 9):

### How to install `perf` userland tool as non-root

1. [Get/find sources for kernel-2.6.36-gentoo-r4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14782/4799) (in Gentoo Linux). The first check from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14782/14784#14784)

   > Actually, *first* you should look at `/usr/src/linux` and see if the kernel sources are still installed. You could just copy them to a directory you can write to.)

   was enough, though instead of copying whole kernel sources I just linked them:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p build
   $ cd build
   $ ln -s /usr/src/linux-2.6.36-gentoo-r4
   ```
2. Create directory where `perf` would be built, as I won't be able to write in `~/build/linux-2.6.36-gentoo-r4` directory.

   ```
   $ mkdir -p perf
   ```

   <sup>Actually it was not what I did at first... error messages from `make` were entirely unhelpful at first.</sup>
3. Go to `tools/perf` directory in kernel sources

   ```
   $ cd linux-2.6.36-gentoo-r4/tools/perf
   ```
4. Build `perf`, **not forgetting about passing `O=<destdir>` option to makefile** as the directory is not writable (there would be no such problem if I copied rather than symlinked kernel sources).

   ```
   $ make O=~/build/perf -k 
   Makefile:565: newt not found, disables TUI support. Please install newt-devel or libnewt-dev
       * new build flags or prefix
       CC ~/build/perf/perf.o
       CC ~/build/perf/builtin-annotate.o
       [...]
       CC ~/build/perf/util/scripting-engines/trace-event-python.o
       CC ~/build/perf/scripts/python/Perf-Trace-Util/Context.o
       AR ~/build/perf/libperf.a
       LINK ~/build/perf/perf
   ~/build/perf/libperf.a(trace-event-perl.o): In function `define_flag_value':
   ~/build/linux-2.6.36-gentoo-r4/tools/perf/util/scripting-engines/trace-event-perl.c:127: undefined reference to `PL_stack_sp'
   ~/build/linux-2.6.36-gentoo-r4/tools/perf/util/scripting-engines/trace-event-perl.c:131: undefined reference to `Perl_push_scope'
   [...]
   ~/build/perf/libperf.a(trace-event-python.o): In function `handler_call_die':
   ~/build/linux-2.6.36-gentoo-r4/tools/perf/util/scripting-engines/trace-event-python.c:53: undefined reference to `PyErr_Print'
   [...]
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   make: *** [/home/narebski/build/perf/perf] Error 1
       GEN perf-archive
   make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
   ```
5. Google for "undefined reference to `Perl_push_scope'". Find [Fail to install perf on slackware 13.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14420/4799) on unix.stackexchange.com. Follow the advice in [self answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14420/14484#14484), or to be more excat the *diagnosis*:

   ```
   $ make O=~/build/perf -k NO_LIBPERL=1 NO_LIBPYTHON=1
   Makefile:565: newt not found, disables TUI support. Please install newt-devel or libnewt-dev
       * new build flags or prefix
       CC ~/build/perf/perf.o
       CC ~/build/perf/builtin-annotate.o
       [...]
       CC ~/build/perf/util/probe-finder.o
       AR ~/build/perf/libperf.a
       LINK ~/build/perf/perf
       GEN perf-archive
   ```

   Note that it is *workaround* rather than a solution (I have `libperl.so`).
6. Check Makefile for default install destination: its `$(HOME)`. Install `perf` in one's own home directory:

   ```
   $ make O=~/build/perf -k NO_LIBPERL=1 NO_LIBPYTHON=1 install
   Makefile:565: newt not found, disables TUI support. Please install newt-devel or libnewt-dev
       GEN perf-archive
   install -d -m 755 '~/bin'
   install ~/build/perf/perf '~/bin'
   [...]
   install scripts/python/bin/* -t '~/libexec/perf-core/scripts/python/bin'
   ```
7. Check that `~/bin` is in PATH
8. Check that `perf` works correctly (don't forget to cd in writable directory):

   ```
   $ cd
   $ perf record -f -- sleep 10
   [ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
   [ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.001 MB perf.data (~61 samples) ]
   ```

The output is a bit redacted, replacing my home directory with `~`.