# Fail to install perf on slackware 13.1

Tags: linux, slackware, perf-event

I was trying to install perf on slackware 13.1
When I first ran make at /usr/src/linux/tools/perf I got some errors.
And I found this patch
http://www.valimar.it/repo/linux/perf_fix-2.6.33.patch
And when I ran make again, it issued some different errors as below.
But I've already installed perl package perl-5.10.1-i486-1

```
libperf.a(trace-event-perl.o): In function `define_flag_value':
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:125: undefined reference to `Perl_push_scope'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:126: undefined reference to `Perl_save_int'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:129: undefined reference to `Perl_newSVpv'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:129: undefined reference to `Perl_sv_2mortal'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:130: undefined reference to `Perl_newSVpv'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:130: undefined reference to `Perl_sv_2mortal'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:131: undefined reference to `Perl_newSVuv'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:131: undefined reference to `Perl_sv_2mortal'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:132: undefined reference to `Perl_newSVpv'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:132: undefined reference to `Perl_sv_2mortal'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:135: undefined reference to `Perl_get_cv'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:136: undefined reference to `Perl_call_pv'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:139: undefined reference to `Perl_free_tmps'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:132: undefined reference to `Perl_stack_grow'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:131: undefined reference to `Perl_stack_grow'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:130: undefined reference to `Perl_stack_grow'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:129: undefined reference to `Perl_stack_grow'
/usr/src/linux-2.6.33.4/tools/perf/util/trace-event-perl.c:127: undefined reference to `Perl_markstack_grow'
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally I solved this problem by just comment out the following line in Makefile

```
#ifndef NO_LIBPERL
#PERL_EMBED_LDOPTS = `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts 2>/dev/null`
#PERL_EMBED_CCOPTS = `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts 2>/dev/null`
#endif
```

It looked like MExtUtils::Embed generate wrong LDFLAGS for libperl
I also found that slackware perl package only provide the static lib libperl.a

Comment: Thanks. This allowed me to solve my isse with `perf` as well (though on Gentoo rather than Slackware, with kernel2.6.36-gentoo-r4)... though instead of modifying Makefile I just ran make with `NO_LIBPERL=1` (though I do have `libperl.so`; I don't know why those errors either).